# Why is it hot before raining?

Tags: temperature, atmospheric-science, geophysics, weather, humidity

What causes the temperature hike before a rain?

I have heard explanations like one that says as the moisture rises, you sweat more.

Can somebody provide a more scientific explanation for this.

Comment: Migrate to [Earth Sciences SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: sorry I mistakenly downvoted your question.  I did not want to leave the downvote as this is the only vote so I reversed my vote from $\downarrow$ to $\uparrow$. I'm quite skeptical of your answer but I'll read more.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero So, do you think my answer is wrong? I mean it can be. Do provide constructive suggestions.

Comment: I dunno if it's right or wrong but I'll certainly read more about it.

Comment: see here: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-determines-rain-temperature-3443616

Comment: It's heat released in the phase transition of water.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When warm humid air flows into cool air the humidity is condensed into rain as the warm air cools. The temperature rise your feeling is the warm humid air rolling into your cooler area before it rains. Your body cools itself by sweat evaporating which disperses your heat into the surrounding atmosphere. If the air is humid the sweat cannot evaporate and you retain heat and feel hot.

Answer (score 4):

Rainfall has a cooling effect. However, it becomes hot and stuffy a short while before rainfall. This is because rainclouds gather in the sky. They are saturated with water and do not allow wind to blow.

Comment: Hurricanes have lots of clouds heavily saturated with water, as well as very high wind speeds. Your theory that clouds don't allow wind to blow doesn't hold up.

Answer (score 0):

The dust particles and the vapours which are present in the atmosphere are also brought down by rain and there is no natural filtration to stop ultra violet rays thus causing heat after rain especially in monsoon because of frequent showers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site! This answer appears to have misunderstood the question; you are answering about an effect _after_ rain but the question is about an effect _before_ rain.

Answer (score 0):

When a thunderstorm develops, the release of latent heat by condensation is 7.5 times as much as the release of latent heat by freezing.
https://www.theweatherprediction.com/habyhints/19/
Now it has to do with h2O bonds hydrogen or van der waals I can’t remember